# PHP explode function takes in more than 1 whitespace, PHP, EXPLODE, WHITESPACES

Tags: php, arrays, whitespace, explode

I have an array with a couple of words, and I'm trying to explode it at only  *one*  whitespace, but its counting whitespaces in as well when exploding for some reason. How do I stop this?

```
<?php

$string = "I'm just            so peachy, right now";
$string = explode(" ", $string);

$count = count($string);
$tempCount = 0;

while ($tempCount < $count) {
echo $string[$tempCount]."$tempCount<br>";
$tempCount++;
}

?>
```

**Actual Output:**

```
I'm0
just1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
so13
peachy,14
right15
now16
```

**Expected Output:**

```
I'm0
just1
so2
peachy,3
right4
now5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a preg_split, http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php, which will use a regex so you can tell it to keep all continuous white-spaces as one.

```
$string = 'I\'m just            so peachy, right now';
$spaced = preg_split('~\h+~', $string);
print_r($spaced);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => I'm
    [1] => just
    [2] => so
    [3] => peachy,
    [4] => right
    [5] => now
)
```

PHP Demo: http://3v4l.org/a5cg5
Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/vO1qU0/1

Comment: What does ~\h+~ mean?

Comment: Horizontal whitespace character (+ means one or more of).

Comment: I forget about `preg_split()`. Great solution.

Comment: Should have added the regex demo at first. Yea, the `\h` is for an inline space (horizontal whitespace). The `+` is for one or more occurance of the previous character. The `~` are delimiters.

Comment: @Zanderwar You guys need to tag whoever down voted you.

Comment: You don't get that information. War-prevention and all :P

Comment: @Zanderwar Well, I was going to upvote it, but you already deleted it.

Comment: Appreciate it Frosty however it's not how stack works. The most efficient answer is this one.